# call Struct member in C

Tags: c

I have a question regarding C, would appreciate those who are willing to share their knowledge.

While I was reading a code, I got stumbbled in a struct that its member is called in a way that I have never seen before.
The code basically is below : 
Code to call the struct member

```
struct struct_name gzw;
gzw.cb = otherfunct;
```

where the struct is defined below

```
struct struct_name {
        int bela;
        unsigned int packet;
        int (*cb)(struct struct_name *fd, unsigned int packet2);
};
```

I kinda confused, because as I know, the cb member should be a pointer, with two parameter isn't it? howcome struct_name can call "cb" , and not (*cb with 2 parameters) ?

Thank you for your kindness response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CB member is a function pointer that takes two parameters and returns and int.  The call you are confused about is assigning a pointer value and therefore does not need to reference the parameters.  to the call the function the parameters would be used `gzw.cb(p1,p2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`cb` is a *function pointer*.  You can assign it to point at any function whose prototype (i.e. argument number, types and return type) matches that of the function-pointer type.

You can then call that function via the function pointer, as:

```
gzw.cb(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: +1 But I prefer to write `gzw.*cb(arg1, arg2);` to write a more portable code.

Comment: @Mahesh: How is that more portable?  In fact, I don't think that's even valid C syntax.

Comment: BTW, I should have written `(gzw.*cb)(arg1, arg2);` . I read in this tutorial when I was preparing on this topic. Please, let me know if this is outdated info. http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#callconv

Answer (score 0):

This is a function pointer. Basically, you assign a function to the struct like you would assign any other value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `cb` is a function pointer that takes two arguments and returns an int.

It is not correct to say "struct_name *calls* `cb`" Instead, the structure contains a function pointer which you can call with `gzw.cb(arg1, arg2);`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right. the member variable cb is a function pointer variable, taking a `struct struct_name*` and an integer as input and returns an int.

To call the function you have to do something like this:

```
int ret = gzw.cb(&gzw, 10);
```